# encoding problem: unable to find the match text only during reboot

Tags: raspbian, python

I have a python file that is running ok if i run it in a terminal in raspberry pi. But if i set it to automatically run after it reboots (using crontab), the file runs ok until it reaches the line where it requires to find the matching Chinese character using regex. I suspect it is related to the encoding. But why the problem only arises in the reboot? Since the output is not shown at startup, I cannot copy the error message. But I really think this is the problem.  Part of the code as below: Edited to output to a log file:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import os
import sys
import requests
import re
import logging 

logging.basicConfig(filename='/home/pi/numbers4d/samlog.log', level=logging.DEBUG)


fetch = requests.get('http://www.check4d.com')   
print fetch
print "============="

match_date = re.search(r'<td class="resultdrawdate">(.+?)</td>' , fetch.text)
print match_date
print "======"

match_M = re.search(r'<td class="resultm4dlable">Magnum 4D 萬能(.+?)</table></div>' , fetch.text)
print("error-check", sys.exc_info()[0])
print match_M
matched = match_M.group()
print matched
logging.debug('error magnum matched obj: %s', matched)
```

What i get in the terminal output is like this:

```
python check4d_r9test.py
<Response [200]>
=============
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x76cb2c20>
======
('error-check', None)
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x76658b60>
<td class="resultm4dlable">Magnum 4D è¬è½</td></tr></table></td></tr><tr><td colspan="5"><table class="resultTable2" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="5"><tr><td class="resultdrawdate">Date: 03-09-2016 (Sat)</td><td class="resultdrawdate">Draw No: 696/16</td></tr></table></td></tr><tr><td colspan="5"><table class="resultTable2" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"><tr><td style="width:45%" class="resultprizelable">1st Prize é¦ç</td><td class="resulttop">3617</td></tr><tr><td style="width:45%" class="resultprizelable">2nd Prize äºç</td><td class="resulttop">5039</td></tr><tr><td style="width:45%" class="resultprizelable">3rd Prize ä¸ç</td><td class="resulttop">4693</td></tr></table></td></tr><tr><td colspan="5" class="resultprizelable">Special ç¹å¥ç</td></tr><tr><td class="resultbottom">7408</td><td class="resultbottom">7013</td><td class="resultbottom">7401</td><td class="resultbottom">7331</td><td class="resultbottom">----</td></tr><tr><td class="resultbottom">0595</td><td class="resultbottom">6838</td><td class="resultbottom">----</td><td class="resultbottom">6984</td><td class="resultbottom">0811</td></tr><tr><td style="width:20%"></td><td class="resultbottom">----</td><td class="resultbottom">2605</td><td class="resultbottom">6854</td><td style="width:20%"></td></tr><tr><td colspan="5" class="resultprizelable">Consolation å®æ°ç</td></tr><tr><td class="resultbottom">6259</td><td class="resultbottom">2958</td><td class="resultbottom">4109</td><td class="resultbottom">0947</td><td class="resultbottom">6402</td></tr><tr><td class="resultbottom">7736</td><td class="resultbottom">5663</td><td class="resultbottom">7370</td><td class="resultbottom">7570</td><td class="resultbottom">9137</td></tr></table></div>
```

But what i get in the output log file (using crontab and output to a file)

```
@reboot sleep 15; python /home/pi/numbers4d/check4d_r9test.py > /home/pi/samlog.log
```

is missing the last part, like this:

```
<Response [200]>
=============
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x76caec20>
======
('error-check', None)
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x171fc60>
```

Comment: Please add the text of the error message to your question.

Comment: I think it has nothing to do with Raspberry Pi. I tried fetching the data you mentioned above but the output of `Match_M` = `None`. There is no match for your regular expression

Comment: @Steve, Actually, there is no way i can see the error message once the python file runs in the background after reboot, unlike if I run it in a terminal after it has booted up. So i can only use logging feature of python and output it to a text file. And the content of the log file become: `INFO:requests.packages.urllib3.connectionpool:Starting new HTTP connection (1): www.check4d.com
DEBUG:requests.packages.urllib3.connectionpool:"GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 None
DEBUG:root:find-the-matchtext: <_sre.SRE_Match object at 0xa4b8e0>
DEBUG:root:true-or-false: 1`

Comment: Try redirecting the output of the script to a file when running it at boot time to see the error. E.g. python myscript.my > /path/to/logfile.log

Comment: @awatts, I have output to a log file as you say, seems like the output log cannot print the match_M. Why is that so?

Comment: There could be a traceback being output to stderr. To redirect stderr to stdout and capture, try something like python my script.py 2>&1 > /path/to/logfile.log

Comment: i have changed the crontab to redirect the stderr to stdout, and yet the result is the same. Somehow the `<td class="resultm4dlable">Magnum 4D è¬è½</td></tr></table></td></tr><tr><td colspan="5"><table class="resultTable2" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="5"><tr>....` is not appear in the log file, but appear if i run it in terminal. Very strange.

Answer (score 0):

After some trials and errors and searching, I am able to make it work.
The logfile will not display the output of the match because the output contains Chinese characters which looks like these... è¬è½
In order to solve this, i make the output text to convert to ascii.

```
matched = match_M.group(0).encode('ascii', 'replace')
```

The whole code now becomes:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import os
import sys
import requests
import re
import logging


logging.basicConfig(filename='/home/pi/numbers4d/samlog.log', level=logging.DEBUG)


fetch = requests.get('http://www.check4d.com')
print "============="

match_date = re.search(ur'<td class="resultdrawdate">(.+?)</td>' , fetch.text)
print match_date
print "======"
print "avuchfcnrcfnc"


match_M = re.search(ur'<td class="resultm4dlable">Magnum 4D 萬能(.+?)</table></div>'.encode('utf-8') , fetch.text)
#match_M = re.search(ur'<td class="resultm4dlable">Magnum 4D(.+?)</table></div>' , fetch.text)
print("error-check", sys.exc_info()[0])
print match_M
matched = match_M.group(0).encode('ascii', 'replace')
#matched = match_M.group(0)
print "xxxx"
print matched
logging.debug('error magnum matched obj: %s', matched)
print "yyyyy"
```

and the output becomes:

```
=============
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x76ce8c20>
======
avuchfcnrcfnc
('error-check', None)
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x7668cea0>
xxxx
<td class="resultm4dlable">Magnum 4D ??????</td></tr></table></td></tr><tr><td c                                                                                        olspan="5"><table class="resultTable2" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="5"><tr><td c                                                                                        lass="resultdrawdate">Date: 28-09-2016 (Wed)</td><td class="resultdrawdate">Draw                                                                                         No: 709/16</td></tr></table></td></tr><tr><td colspan="5"><table class="resultT                                                                                        able2" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"><tr><td style="width:45%" class="resultpr                                                                                        izelable">1st Prize ??????</td><td class="resulttop">7947</td></tr><tr><td style                                                                                        ="width:45%" class="resultprizelable">2nd Prize ??????</td><td class="resulttop"                                                                                        >4237</td></tr><tr><td style="width:45%" class="resultprizelable">3rd Prize ????                                                                                        ??</td><td class="resulttop">7344</td></tr></table></td></tr><tr><td colspan="5"                                                                                         class="resultprizelable">Special ?????????</td></tr><tr><td class="resultbottom                                                                                        ">3820</td><td class="resultbottom">7637</td><td class="resultbottom">----</td><                                                                                        td class="resultbottom">8400</td><td class="resultbottom">8100</td></tr><tr><td                                                                                         class="resultbottom">1358</td><td class="resultbottom">5357</td><td class="resul                                                                                        tbottom">----</td><td class="resultbottom">1948</td><td class="resultbottom">335                                                                                        8</td></tr><tr><td style="width:20%"></td><td class="resultbottom">----</td><td                                                                                         class="resultbottom">6998</td><td class="resultbottom">9648</td><td style="width                                                                                        :20%"></td></tr><tr><td colspan="5" class="resultprizelable">Consolation ???????                                                                                        ??</td></tr><tr><td class="resultbottom">6555</td><td class="resultbottom">5315<                                                                                        /td><td class="resultbottom">2549</td><td class="resultbottom">9428</td><td clas                                                                                        s="resultbottom">4487</td></tr><tr><td class="resultbottom">7778</td><td class="                                                                                        resultbottom">7750</td><td class="resultbottom">3896</td><td class="resultbottom                                                                                        ">5717</td><td class="resultbottom">4682</td></tr></table></div>
yyyyy
```

But i still do not understand why it cannot output unicode/special characters only during startup using crontab, while there is no problem at all running the file in terminal.

Comment: Please accept your own answer with a click on the tick on its left side. Only this will finish the question and it will not pop up again year for year.